# Finding typos in a list of words

Tags: java, algorithm

Given a list of correct words all of length `l` and a list of incorrect words also of length `l`, find the words in the list of incorrect words that differ from the list of corrects words by a swap of two consecutive letters. These words are deemed typos. For example, `hte` is considered a typo of `the` while `het` is not considered a typos.

What is the optimally time efficient algorithm that allows us to find the list of words deemed typos by this definition ?

I was informed that the list may be computed in linear time, but I fail to find the a solution in linear time. The only method I can think of is to compare brute force all the letters from one list with the other.

Comment: Can there be multiple swaps. Is `[la]go[ir]thm` a typo of `algorithm` ?

Comment: Linear in the length of the list or linear in the length of the words?

Comment: Can you use additional space? In that case you can create a hash with keys from the list of correct words. Search becomes constant order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
L - list of correct words of size n.
L'- list of incorrect words of size m.
H - hash table
R - result set

1. for each word w in L :
   1.1  for each typo t of w : //there are l-1 typos
     1.1.1 insert t into H
2. for each word w' in L' :
   2.1 if w' in H insert w' in R
3. return R
```

Time complexity :
    `O(n*l)+O(m) = O(max(n*l,m))`

Space complexity :
    `O(n*l)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there can only be single swaps in each "typo"'ed word:

Start with an empty HashTable H.

For each word K in list of INCORRECT words:

- Generate (l-1) new words by swapping each pair of consecutive characters: K_1, K_2, ..., K_x, ..., K_(l-1)

  - For each of these new words, add it to the HashTable H with the key as K_x and the value as K (the original incorrect word)

Now for each word C in the list of CORRECT words, :

- For each C, check if the key C exists in in HashTable H.
- If key C exists in HashTable H, output the value C' associated with C: since the values are all originally from the list of INCORRECT words, we must have found an incorrect word where, by swapping 2 consecutive letters, turned it into a correct word.
- Output each such C'

Since l is a fixed number (it must be, for otherwise you can grow both l and n into infinity at the same time and there is no linear time algorithm otherwise), you have the following run-time complexities:

- It takes linear time to go through the incorrect words list
- It takes constant time l to generate new words for each word in the incorrect words list
- It takes constant time to add each (new word, K) to the HashTable H
- It takes linear time to go through the correct words list
- It takes constant time to check each word in the correct words list against the HashTable H

Therefore this is O(n) run-time.

Answer (score 0):

```
findTypos(List CORRECT_LIST,
List INCORRECT_LIST,
List TYPOS_OUTPUT_LIST) {
 boolean INCORRECT_LIST_EMPTY = false  

 for each element in CORRECT_LIST {  
    TYPOS = computeTypos(element)  
    for each typo in TYPOS  
        if(INCORRECT_LIST.contains(typo)) {  
            INCORRECT_LIST.remove(typo)  
            TYPOS_OUTPUT_LIST.add(typo)  
        }  
        if(INCORRECT_LIST.size() == 0) {  
            INCORRECT_LIST_EMPTY = true;  
            break;  
        }  
    }  
    if(INCORRECT_LIST_EMPTY) {  
        break;  
    }  
 }
 return TYPOS_OUTPUT_LIST;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for SINGLE swap case. I am assuming there is only one swap per word. So, for word `algorithm`, `algo[ir]thm` is a valid typo; while `[la]go[ir]thm` is invalid.

Lets call the correct word list `A` and the other list `B`.

1. create a hash-Table, `HB` of incorrect words from list `B`. Hash function like this

   ```
   Σ(ai*10i); where 0 <= i <  a.length, ai = int value of character at index i
   ```

   This is `O(l)`.

2.Iterate in `A`.

```
(assume base 1 index)

typo = []
for i = 1 to A.length
  for j = A[i].length down-to 2
    temp = swap(A[i], j, j-1)
    hash = getHash(temp)
    if(HB.has(hash))
      typo.add(temp)
return typo
```

You see the two loops? How many times they execute? Lets do maths

```
a1.length + a2.length + .. +al.length - l
(the minus l is because we are actually iterating one less in each words)
= length_of_all_characters_the_list_A - l
```

But how do I get order? Well, big O is upper boundary, so

```
O(l*max(A[i].length)
=> O(l*m)
```